# Qual a melhor estratégia para atualizar dados somente quando necessário?

Tags: api, rest, cache, react-native

Em uma aplicação com `React Native`, usando `Redux` e `Redux-Persist`, qual a melhor forma de identificar que o conteúdo precisa ser atualizado?

No meu caso, tenho um aplicativo que faz algumas requisições no start up.
Quando habilitei o `redux-persist` passei a evitar a requisição caso já tivesse sido feita em outro momento. Mas não tenho idéia de qual a melhor forma de identificar agora se devo ou não liberar a requisição novamente para atualizar os dados armazenados pelo `redux-persist`.

Li sobre utilizar `ETags` e `Last-Modified`, mas isso implica em implementar isso na API também correto?

Alguma orientação para ter essa funcionalidade implementada do jeito certo?

Comment: bem complicado por que vai depender muito da sua aplicação e dos dados necessarios no momento, ex, normalmente os dados do perfil precisam de uma frequencia de atualizacao menor. Pra resolver pode colocar um botao de refresh onde for necessario.

Comment: Pensei em colocar um pullToRefresh nesse locais onde os dados não sofrem atualização direto. Esses posso manter em cache por bastante tempo, mas os dados que são constantemente atualizados, não vejo outra forma além de salvar algo que indique a última alteração. Por isso queria saber se alguém já tinha feito algo nesse sentido.